# In VScode , How to open a file under cursor in peek window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is an extension `"Open File"` which helps me to open a file under cursor in vscode using `alt+p` .

Some times I would like to open a file in Peek windows. I am using ansible which doesn't have peek definition so I could not use `alt+f12.`

Is there any extension to open a file under cursor in peek window?

Comment: try this one 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Fr43nk.seito-openfile

Answer (score 1):

The peek window is just a view of a separate file. It does not, by itself, represent a file. Hence you cannot open a file in it.